# Dynamics crm 365 get azure adal authorization code

Tags: azure, dynamics-crm, azure-active-directory, dynamics-crm-2013

I have a scenario is one where the user has signed into CRM and triggers some functionality that calls a third party API to retrieve data that is not in CRM.
This API is a registered application in the Same Azure Active Directory as where the CRM resides. CRM single sign on is enabled.

I am trying to find an example of C# code which retrieves the authorization code via a CRM plugin. So far, I have managed to retrieve the token using a client secret as described in this article:

[Retrieving token without the ADAL client library](http://www.zacrmguy.com/alternative-to-azure-authentication-with-adal-in-dynamics-crm-online-sandbox/)

I have implemented a basic call with the parameters defined in this article:

[Requesting an Authorization code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code)

But I need to pass the user session to make it work. It currently throws an error

> A silent sign-in request was sent but no user is signed in. The cookies used to represent the user's session were not sent in the request to Azure AD. This can happen if the user is using Internet Explorer or Edge, and the web app sending the silent sign-in request is in different IE security zone than the Azure AD endpoint (login.microsoftonline.com).

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, it is not suitable to interact with Azure AD using the Oauth code grant flow in the Microsoft Dynamics 365 plug-in since it required users interaction. And it is not able to send the session in the Microsoft Dynamics 365 plug-in to authenticate using ADAL library.

If you only want to access the Microsoft Dynamics 365 organization service in the CRM plug-in, there is no need to use the ADAL library to authenticate again.

It is only required that plug-in code create an instance of the service through the ServiceProvider.GetService method.

```
// Obtain the organization service reference.
IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);
```

More detail about context of Microsoft Dynamics 365 Plug-in development, please refer the link below:

[Understand the data context passed to a plug-in](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309673.aspx#bkmk_access)

Comment: Thanks for the response, I am trying to access another application registered in the same Azure AD. You are correct about sending the session data to the plugin. I don't think it is going to work accept by using javascript to read the sessionid from the cookie and passing it to a workflow plugin via an action. We might have to just settle on using the client secret.